# Reading in CSV columns as categorical variables using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Can pandas recognise which columns in the dataframe are categorical without us specifying the columns explicitly while reading a csv file.
Something similar to StringAsFactor in R.
I tried searching but what I get is either we creating the column as Categorical or specifying which column to consider as categorical while reading a file. I need pandas to identify.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance !!

Comment: How does the csv file look like?

Comment: @Dark it has some 25 columns which can be of either continuous or categorical type

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can specify what columns are of categorical type when loading them using `read_*`. For example, consider a sample CSV -

```
Col
a
b
c
a
b
b
c
```

Now, read this in with `read_csv`, specifying a `dtype` argument -

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype={'Col' : 'category'})
```

```
df['Col']

0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
4    b
5    b
6    c
Name: Col, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a, b, c]
```

---

If you have an unknown number of categorical columns, you can read them in and then convert them one by one -

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == object]: # df.dtypes == 'object'
    df[c] = df[c].astype('category')
```

Comment: Ya I am aware of this. But here we should know which columns are categorical so that we can mention them in "dtype" parameter. But I wanted pandas to identify without me explicitly mentioning.

Comment: @Learner How would pandas know whether a column is string or categorical? It isn't possible with the current API.

Comment: @Learner However, if all your non-numerical columns are categorical, then the solution simplifies. You can transform it post reading.

Comment: Okay so it has to be post reading. I was expecting to have a parameter like StringAsFactor parameter available in R data.table package so that it will be done while reading.

Comment: @Learner Edited my answer, that's the only way as of now.

Comment: @COLDSPEED thanks for the answer. Just a thought that I had. Sometimes the data might contain "date" column which will also be referred as object by pandas, what in such scenarios

Comment: @Learner You can change the condition slightly: `df.columns[(df.dtypes == object) & ~df.columns.str.contains('Date')]`